# What Java data type will Date of Birth be?

Tags: java, type-conversion, date

I am currently making an App on Android where a user will Register their details.

In my database I have DOB as a `Date` type.

Would I declare DOB in Java as a `String`? `Double`? `Int`? I'm confused how I will go about this so it satisfies the database's Date format.

Any help will be great!

Comment: Usually one would indeed go about storing a birth date as date object. But this depends on the application and the underlying database. Can you provide some more info?

Comment: Well in the database the users date of birth would be stored as a 'DATE' Type, so in my Java program, when I declare the objects:
`public class User {
    String firstName, lastName, email, school, sType, password;
    int dob;`

would it be something like that? I'm aware it wouldn't be Int, but what would it be?

Comment: You can store a date as an int (e.g. as a Julian day); it is easier to work with if you use `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 14):

A [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (or logically-equivalent classes likes [`org.joda.time.LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html)) is the best way to represent a date-of-birth (DOB) in Java code.

Note that DOB is *not* well-modelled as a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), or a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html): these model *instants* in time, not timezone-independent dates.

Whilst one is clearly born at some instant in time, this is not how we, societally, report when we are born. Consider that two children born at the same instant in different time zones might actually have different dates of birth - if the child in NYC is born at 2AM on 1st April, the child born in LA is born at 10PM on 31st March.

Neither child's date of birth changes when they travel to the other city (or anywhere else, of course). As such, if you store the *instant* of birth, you also need to store the time zone of birth in order to correctly interpret that instant as the *date* of birth.

But storing an instant *and* a timezone is inconvenient: not only is it more data to store, but also it is difficult to interpret it "by eye" (e.g. it's hard to tell what date `(1459438541000, America/Los_Angeles)` refers to). It is much easier to store and interpret the year, month and day directly: `(2016, 3, 31)`.

Comment: So once I import `java.time.LocalDate`,  how do I implement it so that a User using the app can enter their data of birth if I've declared DOB as `int dob`, how can I make (2016, 3, 31) acceptable as an int?

Comment: Well, I'm advising that you store it as a `LocalDate`, not an `int`. But if you have to store it as an `int` (which gets back to the problem of "what does date `1459438541000`" mean above), you can store it as the number of days after a given datum, e.g. a Julian date.

Comment: * I'm advising that you *represent it in your Java code* as a `LocalDate`. You can persist it however it is convenient.

Comment: @AndyTurner Excellent Answer is except for one problem: `java.sql.Date` does indeed pretend to be a date-only value along the lines of `java.time.LocalDate`. `java.sql.Date` inherits (awkwardly) from `java.util.Date`. So it does indeed contain the time-of-day but sets that to `00:00:00.0` in a poorly designed attempt to fake being a local date rather than an instant-in-time as you indicated. We do use `java.sql.Date` as the class for moving `java.time.LocalDate` values in/out of the database, until our JDBC drivers are updated to handle java.time types directly.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, it *pretends* to be that, but it doesn't change the fundamental representation as an instant. It is a lot more error-prone than using `LocalDate` - for instance, the output of `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new java.sql.Date(0)))` depends upon JVM configuration. I'm not saying it's not possible to use it, just it requires a lot more care than `LocalDate`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Okay, agreed.